# Git commit using stdout from bash?

Tags: pipe, git

Is it possible to use a commit message from stdout, like:

```
echo "Test commit" | git commit -
```

Tried also to echo the message content in `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, but then running `git commit` would ask to add changes in mentioned file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `-F <file>, --file=<file>` option.

```
echo "Test commit" | git commit -F -
```

Its usage is described in the man page for `git commit`:

> Take the commit message from the given file. Use - to read the message from
>   the standard input.

Comment: Missed this option while reading `man` :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could always write a little function for it:

```
gcm(){ 
    read message
    git commit -m "$message" "$@"
}
```

Add that to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent for your shell, and then run:

```
echo "Test commit" | gcm filename.to.commit
```

The command above will run

```
git commit -m "Test commit" filename.to.commit
```

Comment: I think you meant `echo "Test commit" | gcm filename.to.commit`.

Comment: @user2313067 d'oh! Yes I did, of course. Thanks!